# How to prove the bisector vector of the angle formed by three consecutive points on a helix is perpendicular to direction

Tags: geometry

I have a problem shown in the title.

The problem comes from a paper named "DEFINING THE AXIS OF A HELIX"[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOd6O.png), where it stated that "Construct vector PI from the origin to carbon alpha 2 (CA2). From CA2, construct vectors A and B to CA1, and CA3, respectively. The bisector of the angle defined by A and B will be perpendicular to the helix axis and will intersect it." I am wondering how to prove this? Does length of vector A and B should be the same?

Thank you.

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOd6O.png)Peter C. Kahn, Defining the axis of a helix, Computers & Chemistry, Volume 13, Issue 3, 1989, Pages 185-189

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the following I'm assuming some regularity of your helix and the placement of the points you consider on it.

Let's parametrize the helix as follows.
$$
h(t) = (a\cos t, a\sin t, bt)\quad for \quad t \in \mathbb R
$$
with real constants $a,b > 0$. The first coordinate of $h(t)$ is the $x$-coordinate, the second is the $y$-coordinate, and the third is the $z$-coordinate with coordinate axis as in your picture. The axis of symmetry is the $z$-axis. As $t$ increases, $h(t)$ spirals upwards around the $z$-axis with "radius" $a$. $b$ is the "height covered by the helix in one complete revolution".

By symmetry, we can assume
$$
P1 = h(0) = (a,0,0).
$$
We want $P1$ to be "in the middle" between the points $P1+A$ and $P1+B$. This means we pick $P1+B$ at height (i.e. $z$-coordinate) $b\tau$ for some $\tau > 0$ and $P1+A$ at the negative height $-b\tau.$ Note that a point on the helix is uniquely determined by its height, since given the height (i.e. $z$-coordinate), we can reconstruct the parameter $t$ and thus the whole point $h(t)$. Thus, we must have
$$
P1+B = h(\tau) \quad and \quad P1+A = h(-\tau).
$$
This leads us to
$$
\begin{align}
B & = h(\tau)-P1 \\
& = h(\tau)-h(0) \\
& =(a\cos\tau-a,a\sin\tau,b\tau),
\end{align}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
A & = h(-\tau)-P1 \\
& = h(-\tau)-h(0) \\
& =(a\cos(-\tau)-a,a\sin(-\tau),-b\tau) \\
& =(a\cos\tau-a,-a\sin\tau,-b\tau).
\end{align}
$$
From this, we get
$$
\frac{1}{2}(B+A) = (a\cos\tau-a,0,0).
$$
Now, the line $L$ through $P1$ bisecting the segment from $P1+A$ to $P1+B$ consists of the points
$$
\begin{align}
P1+\lambda\frac{1}{2}\left((P1+B)+(P1+A)\right) & = P1+\lambda\frac{1}{2}(B+A) \\
& = (a,0,0)+\lambda(a\cos\tau-a,0,0) \\
& = (a+\lambda (a\cos\tau-a),0,0)
\end{align}
$$
with parameter $\lambda\in\mathbb R.$ We want this line to intersect the helix axis, i.e. the $z$-axis. To this end we have to solve
$$
0 = a+\lambda (a\cos\tau-a)
$$
and arrive at
$$
\lambda = \frac{1}{1-\cos\tau}.
$$
Here we must exclude the case $\cos\tau = 1.$ But this is perfectly reasonable, since $\cos\tau=1$ iff $\tau \in 2\pi\mathbb Z$ iff $A$ and $B$ are parallel to the $z$-axis iff $P1+B$ and $P1+A$ are located (in the direction of the $z$-axis) "over" resp "under" $P1$ on the helix. In this case, the midpoint of the segment from $P1+A$ to $P1+B$ is the point $P1$. So in this case the line $L$ degenerates to the point $P1$. It's reasonable to exclude this case.

So we have that the line $L$ from above intersects the $z$-axis. Since the direction of $L$ is given by $\frac{1}{2}(B+A)$, we see from the coordinates of this vector calculated above that $L$ is perpendicular to the $z$-axis. And to answer the final part of your question, yes, in all these calculations $A$ and $B$ have the same length. Otherwise we don't have enough symmetry.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is very helpful.